System-level rate limit exceeded in Python despite using multiple proxies, each called only once
I’m encountering an issue with rate limits in my Python code, even though I’m using multiple proxies and ensuring that each proxy is called only once. Despite this, I keep receiving the error:

"System-level rate limit exceeded."

Here’s an overview of my setup:
I have a list of proxies, and I’m using each proxy only for a single request, each proxy only call once (but using thread to call many request at a time).
However, after a few requests, I still get the rate limit error.
Here is a simplified version of my Python code:
def _request(self, method, uri, timeout=5, auth=True, params=None):
                   
        uri_path = uri
        data_json = ''
        if method in ['GET', 'DELETE']:
            if params:
                strl = []
                for key in sorted(params):
                    strl.append("{}={}".format(key, params[key]))
                data_json += '&'.join(strl)
                uri += '?' + data_json
                uri_path = uri
                
        else:
            if params:
                data_json = json.dumps(params)

                uri_path = uri + data_json

        headers = {}
        if auth:
            now_time = int(time.time()) * 1000
            str_to_sign = str(now_time) + method + uri_path
            sign = base64.b64encode(
                hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'), str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
            if self.is_v1api:
                headers = {
                    "KC-API-SIGN": sign,
                    "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(now_time),
                    "KC-API-KEY": self.key,
                    "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": self.passphrase,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            else:
                passphrase = base64.b64encode(
                    hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'), self.passphrase.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
                headers = {
                    "KC-API-SIGN": sign,
                    "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(now_time),
                    "KC-API-KEY": self.key,
                    "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphrase,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2"
                }
        headers["User-Agent"] = "kucoin-python-sdk/"+version
        url = urljoin(self.url, uri)

        proxy_dict = {'http': self.cl_proxy, 'https': self.cl_proxy} #if self.cl_proxy else None
        #print (url,proxy_dict)
        if method in ['GET', 'DELETE']:
            r = requests.request(method, url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout, proxies=proxy_dict)
        else:
            r = requests.request(method, url, headers=headers, data=data_json, timeout=timeout, proxies=proxy_dict)
        
        if ("System-level rate limit exceeded"):
            s = str(url) + str(self.key)+ str(proxy_dict ) + str(r.status_code)
            print (s)


This question would be easier to answer if you provided a [mcve] -- minimal code that is runnable without modification and that reproduces the problem you're asking about. For example, it's not obvious from this code that you're "using each proxy only for a single request"; what is self.cl_proxy and how is it assigned?
